# Is Voldemort evil to pure-bloods?

Tags: harry-potter, voldemort, pure-blood

You-know-who was originally not a blood supremacist, and just generically evil. So was he evil to pure-bloods? ( not counting blood traitors). Asking partially because in [cursed child](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harry_Potter_and_the_Cursed_Child) Draco said that his father had preferred a world without Voldemort.

Comment: Do you mean, was Voldemort considered evil *by* Pure-bloods? Or do you mean, was he antagonistic towards Pure-bloods, Half-bloods, and Muggles/Muggle-borns alike?

Comment: Hagrid contends that the very concept of "pure-blood" is rubbish. But, given the general consensus of how pure-blood is used in-universe, the Weaselys would fall under that umbrella, and...they meet either interpretation of this question. They considered him evil, and he and his followers were antagonistic towards them

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does Voldemort hate half-bloods?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/201626/why-does-voldemort-hate-half-bloods)

Comment: @NKCampbell The Weasleys are "blood traitors", though, so I think the OP means "did ALL other purebloods who didn't like muggles follow Voldemort's fantasy-racism", maybe?

Comment: @NKCambell Wouldn’t the Weasleys count as “blood traitors”, though?

Comment: I have no Idea whatyoz are asking... but as Voldemort killed some pure bloods that are not blood traiters, I‘d say: yes, he was evil for everybody except his followers

Answer (score 7):

## Some pure-bloods thought he went too far.

Many pure-bloods supported the Dark Lord, but as Sirius tells Harry, there were some pure-bloods who weren’t blood traitors and thought the Dark Lord had the right idea, but who didn’t like what he was willing to do to get power.

> “Come on, Harry, haven’t you seen enough of this house to tell what kind of wizards my family were?’ said Sirius testily.
>
> ‘Were – were your parents Death Eaters as well?’
>
> ‘No, no, but believe me, they thought Voldemort had the right idea, they were all for the purification of the wizarding race, getting rid of Muggle-borns and having pure-bloods in charge. They weren’t alone, either, there were quite a few people, before Voldemort showed his true colours, who thought he had the right idea about things … they got cold feet when they saw what he was prepared to do to get power, though. But I bet my parents thought Regulus was a right little hero for joining up at first.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix, Chapter 6 (The Noble and Most Ancient House of Black)*</sup></sub>

There were, therefore, several pure-bloods who weren’t blood traitors but who didn’t support the Dark Lord.

## The Dark Lord tried to spare pure-bloods.

Though the Dark Lord was certainly willing to kill, he didn’t kill pure-bloods if he could avoid it. He usually gives pure-bloods who oppose him a chance to join him instead. Despite Neville Longbottom’s clear resistance to him, he still offers Neville a chance to join the Death Eaters, he doesn’t just kill him.

> “But you are a pure-blood, aren’t you, my brave boy?’ Voldemort asked Neville, who stood facing him, his empty hands curled in fists.
>
> ‘So what if I am?’ said Neville loudly.
>
> ‘You show spirit, and bravery, and you come of noble stock. You will make a very valuable Death Eater. We need your kind, Neville Longbottom.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows, Chapter 36 (The Flaw in the Plan)*</sup></sub>

The Death Eaters also avoided killing pure-bloods. Neville told Harry he knew that the members of Dumbledore’s Army were fairly safe because the Death Eaters didn’t want to spill too much pure blood.

> “Neville shrugged.
> ‘Doesn’t matter. They don’t want to spill too much pure blood, so they’ll torture us a bit if we’re mouthy but they won’t actually kill us.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows, Chapter 29 (The Lost Diadem)*</sup></sub>

The Dark Lord was also willing to spare the lives of wizards who weren’t pure-blood. At Hogwarts, he offered all those fighting him a chance to join him, and said that every drop of magical blood spilled is a waste. He offered mercy to all except Mudbloods.

> “You have fought,’ said the high, cold voice, ‘valiantly. Lord Voldemort knows how to value bravery.
>
> ‘Yet you have sustained heavy losses. If you continue to resist me, you will all die, one by one. I do not wish this to happen. Every drop of magical blood spilled is a loss and a waste.
>
> ‘Lord Voldemort is merciful. I command my forces to retreat, immediately.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows, Chapter 33 (The Prince’s Tale)*</sup></sub>

The only blood statuses that the Dark Lord targeted were Mudbloods and blood traitors. Though he’d kill specific pure-bloods or half-bloods if necessary, he attempted to avoid it.